# Prove binomial coefficient

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

Equality of Binomial coefficients.
I was wondering why these two **Binomial coefficients** (x is just a place holder):

$\binom{x}{ k!(n+1-k)!}$ = $\binom{x}{k!(n-k)!}$.
Both lead to $\binom{x}{k}$.
Does the answer come from Pascal's triangle?
I don't get it. Why is it equal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an identity.

For example, if $x=6, k=1, n=3$ then I would have thought $\binom{x}{ k!(n+1-k)!}=\binom{6}{ 1!\times3!}=\binom{6}{ 6}=1$ while $\binom{x}{ k!(n-k)!}=\binom{6}{ 1!\times2!}=\binom{6}{ 2}=15$ and $\binom{x}{k}=\binom{6}{1}=6$

So let's instead treat $\binom{x}{ k!(n+1-k)!} =  \binom{x}{ k!(n-k)!}$ as an equation.

This requires one of:

- $x < k!(n-k)!$  and $n \ge k$

  - which would give $0=0$.  That is not particularly interesting
- $x=k!$ and $n=k$

  - so $k!(n+1-k)! = k!(n-k)!=k!$ to give $1 = 1$
- $x=k!(n-k)!(n+2-k)$ and $n \ge k$

  - so  $k!(n+1-k)! = x - k!(n-k)!$ to give $\binom{k!(n-k)!(n+2-k)}{ k!(n+1-k)!} =  \binom{k!(n-k)!(n+2-k)}{ k!(n-k)!}$